# Lock objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am using the `multiprocessing.Pool` class within an object and attempting the following:

```
from multiprocessing import Lock, Pool

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.file = open('test.txt')
    def function(self, i):
        self.lock.acquire()
        line = self.file.readline()
        self.lock.release()
        return line
    def anotherfunction(self):
        pool = Pool()
        results = pool.map(self.function, range(10000))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        return results
```

However I am getting a runtime error stating that lock objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance. I am fairly new to Python and multiprocessing. How can I get put on the right track?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you should send `self.Lock` to `self.function` as second argument.

Comment: you forgot `self` in functions definitions. - `def function(self)`, `def anotherfunction(self)`

Comment: For furture readers, it is possible to create picklable locks that work with pools, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75247561/16310741

Answer (score 9):

`multiprocessing.Lock` instances can be attributes of `multiprocessing.Process` instances. When a process is created in the main process with a lock attribute, the lock exists in the main process’s address space. When the process’s `start` method is invoked and runs a subprocess which invokes the process’s `run` method, the lock has to be serialized/deserialized to the subprocess address space. This works as expected:

```py
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process

class P(Process):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Process.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.lock = Lock()
    def run(self):
        print(self.lock)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = P()
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Prints:

```
<Lock(owner=None)>
```

Unfortuantely, this does not work when you are dealing with `multiprocessing.Pool` instances. In your example, `self.lock` is created in the main process by the `__init__` method. But when `Pool.map` is called to invoke `self.function`, the lock cannot be serialized/deserialized to the already-running pool process that will be running this method.

The solution is to initialize each pool process with a global variable set to this lock (there is no point in having this lock being an attribute of the class now). The way to do this is to use the *initializer* and *initargs* parameters of the pool `__init__` method. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool#module-multiprocessing.pool):

```py
from multiprocessing import Lock, Pool

def init_pool_processes(the_lock):
    '''Initialize each process with a global variable lock.
    '''
    global lock
    lock = the_lock

class Test:
    def function(self, i):
        lock.acquire()
        with open('test.txt', 'a') as f:
            print(i, file=f)
        lock.release()
    def anotherfunction(self):
        lock = Lock()
        pool = Pool(initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(lock,))
        pool.map(self.function, range(10))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test()
    t.anotherfunction()
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the first 4 issues you cited. Sorry for the confusion. In your code you listed, why is lock defined as global in init_pool_processes after it is instantiated in anotherfunction()?

Comment: `anotherfunction` is executing in the main process and `function` is a "worker function" that is invoked as a result of the call to `pool.map` by one of the processes in the multiprocessing pool you created and is therefore running in a completely different process/address space. You need to pass the `lock` instance from one address space to another and the only way to do that when dealing with a multiprocessing pool is to initialize for each process in the pool a global variable with the lock. This is how you initialize "by inheritance". Read the documentation at the link I posted.

Comment: So is the worker function a static copy of the class method?

Comment: On Windows to launch a new process a new, empty address space is created and a new Python interpreter is  launched that re-reads the source file re-creating the class definition and its methods in the new address space before the worker function can be invoked. So if that is what you mean by a "static copy of the class method", then yes.

Comment: If this answers your question, feel free to *Accept* the answer.