# Python multiprocessing: Queue not synchronized

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing

I am currently writing a multithreaded client for making HTTP requests with a rate-limit, and for that I am using a 'manager' Process, that handles the ratelimit and enqueues new requests into the Pool.

For some reason, the queue doesn't seem to get synchronized between the class, the manager, and the worker processes.

### Code

```py
from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue, Pool, Value
from multiprocessing.dummy import Process
from time import time
from typing import Callable

import requests
from requests import Request, Response


class HTTPWorkerPool:
    def __init__(self, requests: int, period: float, processes: int = None, daemon: bool = False):
        self._pool = Pool(processes=processes)
        self._queue = JoinableQueue()
        self.rps = Value('f', 0.0)
        self._running = Value('b', True)
        self._manager = Process(name='fastclient-manager', target=self._manager_, args=(period,
                                requests, self._pool, self._queue, self.rps, self._running))
                                
        self._manager.daemon = True
        self._manager.start()

    def __del__(self):
        self.join()

    def _manager_(self, period, requests, pool, queue, rps, running):
        limited = False
        current_requests = 0
        last_clear = 0.0

        while running.value:
            if queue.empty():
                continue  # keep waiting for input. If join wasn't called, this will still be used.

            if current_requests >= requests:
                limited = True

            current_time = time()

            if last_clear + period <= current_time:
                rps.value = current_requests/(current_time-last_clear)
                last_clear = current_time
                limited = False
                current_requests = 0

            if not limited:
                print(f'in queue {queue.qsize()}')
                pool.apply_async(self._worker, queue)
                current_requests += 1

    def _worker(self, queue: JoinableQueue):
        (req, cb) = queue.get()
        cb(requests.send(req.prepare()))
        queue.task_done()

    def join(self):
        self._queue.close()
        self._queue.join()
        self._running.value = False
        self._manager.join()
        self._pool.close()
        self._pool.terminate()
        self._pool.join()

    def submit(self, request: Request, callback: Callable[[Response], None]):
        self._queue.put((request, callback))
```

and for testing

```py
from time import sleep
from fastclient import HTTPWorkerPool
from requests import Request


def cb(res):
    print(res.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = HTTPWorkerPool(10, 1)
    for _ in range(100):
        pool.submit(Request(method='GET', url='https://httpbin.org/get'), cb)

    for _ in range(10):
        sleep(1)
        print(pool.rps.value)
```

The output is a bunch of `100`s (the queue length) and every second `9.9...` (the requests-per-second).

The queue length keeps staying at `100` and doesn't decrease.

Does someone know, how I can properly synchronise the queue(s), in order to have the tasks completed?

Answer (score 0):

---

There are a few mistakes here.

### Unpicklable attributes

Inside `_manager_` you are creating tasks inside the pool with the target as  `self._worker`. For this to work, the `self` would need to be pickled as well. However, your instance is unpicklable since it contains an object of `Pool` and a an object of `Process`. The only reason the instance was pickled when creating the `_manager_` process was because the `Process` handles pickling a little [different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69913167/16310741) from the `Pool` class.

So, since `_worker` does not use any instance attributes anyway, you can make it a function outside the class, or a staticmethod of the class.

### Not creating a managed queue

You cannot share queues as arguments to processes in pools:

```
from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue, Pool


def a(pool):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(1)
    q = JoinableQueue()

    p1 = p.apply_async(a, (q,))

    p1.get()
```

**Output**

```
RuntimeError: JoinableQueue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

You can however, create a queue through managers which basically share a proxy of the queue, instead of the actual queue, allowing it to be pickled.

```
from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue, Pool, Manager


def a(pool):
    print('all done')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = Manager()
    p = Pool(1)
    q = m.JoinableQueue()

    p1 = p.apply_async(a, (q,))
```

**Output**

```
all done
```

### Not using error callbacks

This probably forms the crux of the issue. Your code is actually constantly returning errors whenever you try try and spawn a `_worker`, but you will never know that since you haven't specified an [error callback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async), and neither are you doing `.get()` to the tasks you spawn using the pool.

When you create a task using `apply_async`, the return value is an [AsycnResult](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult), which acts similar to a promise. The results (or exceptions raised) are only provided to you after you wait for this pseudo-promise to resolve using `.get()`, or, by using callbacks, for *both*, errors and successful results. Since you are doing neither, you will never know what actually happened when you spawned the worker except the fact that it did not work.

### Syntax

**Firstly**, the function `pool.apply_async` accepts the second argument as an iterable of arguments which will be unpacked to the target function. Even if the target function accepts only one argument, they still need to be an iterable when passed to `apply_async`. Therefore, this line:

```
pool.apply_async(type(self)._worker, queue)
```

Should become this:

```
pool.apply_async(type(self)._worker, (queue,))
```

**Secondly**, when you are sending prepared requests using `requests`, you need to send them using a session. Hence this line:

```
cb(requests.send(req.prepare()))
```

Should become this:

```
cb(requests.Session().send(req.prepare()))
```

### Final code

Fixing all these errors will result in your code somewhat like this:

```
from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue, Pool, Value, Manager
from multiprocessing.dummy import Process
from time import time
from typing import Callable
from queue import Queue

import requests
from requests import Request, Response


class HTTPWorkerPool:
    def __init__(self, requests: int, period: float, processes: int = None, daemon: bool = False):

        manager = Manager()
        self._pool = Pool(processes=processes)
        self._queue = manager.JoinableQueue()
        self.rps = Value('f', 0.0)
        self._running = Value('b', True)
        self._manager = Process(name='fastclient-manager', target=self._manager_, args=(period,
                                                                                        requests, self._pool,
                                                                                        self._queue, self.rps,
                                                                                        self._running))

        self._manager.daemon = True
        self._manager.start()

    def __del__(self):
        self.join()

    def _manager_(self, period, requests, pool, queue, rps, running):
        limited = False
        current_requests = 0
        last_clear = 0.0

        while running.value:
            if queue.empty():
                continue  # keep waiting for input. If join wasn't called, this will still be used.

            if current_requests >= requests:
                limited = True

            current_time = time()

            if last_clear + period <= current_time:
                rps.value = current_requests / (current_time - last_clear)
                last_clear = current_time
                limited = False
                current_requests = 0

            if not limited:
                print(f'in queue {queue.qsize()}')
                pool.apply_async(type(self)._worker, (queue,))
                current_requests += 1
    @staticmethod
    def _worker(queue: JoinableQueue):
        (req, cb) = queue.get()
        cb(requests.Session().send(req.prepare()))
        queue.task_done()

    def join(self):
        self._queue.close()
        self._queue.join()
        self._running.value = False
        self._manager.join()
        self._pool.close()
        self._pool.terminate()
        self._pool.join()

    def submit(self, request: Request, callback: Callable[[Response], None]):
        self._queue.put((request, callback))
```

Don't forget to pass an error callback to help in debugging in future.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:

1. Method `empty` called on a `multiprocessing.Queue` or `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue` is not reliable and should not be used.
2. Module `requests` does not have a function named `send`.
3. Your tasks (fetching URLs) are perhaps better suited for multithreading rather than multiprocessing.

Consider using the following simpler `RateLimitedProcessPool` or `RateLimitedThreadPool` classes, which are more general purpose, as a starting point:

```
import multiprocessing.pool
import multiprocessing
import threading
from functools import wraps
import time

class RateLimitedPool:
    # There is an a lag between the first call to apply_async and the first task actually starting.
    # Err on the side of this being too large:
    LAG_TIME = .2 # seconds - needs to be fine-tuned:

    def __init__(self, rate, per):
        assert isinstance(rate, int) and rate > 0
        assert isinstance(per, (int, float)) and per > 0
        self.rate = rate
        self.per = per
        self.count = 0
        self.start_time = None

    def _check_allowed(self):
        if self.start_time is None: # first time
            self.start_time = time.time() + self.LAG_TIME
            self.count = 1
            return
        if self.count < self.rate:
            self.count += 1
            return
        # Start of a new batch:
        self.count = 1
        current_time = time.time()
        time_to_wait = self.per - (current_time - self.start_time)
        if time_to_wait > 0:
            time.sleep(time_to_wait)
            current_time = time.time()
        self.start_time = current_time

    def apply_async(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._check_allowed()
        return super().apply_async(*args, **kwargs)

class RateLimitedProcessPool(RateLimitedPool, multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    def __init__(self, *args, rate=5, per=1, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.pool.Pool.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        RateLimitedPool.__init__(self, rate, per)

class RateLimitedThreadPool(RateLimitedPool, multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool):
    def __init__(self, *args, rate=5, per=1, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.pool.Pool.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        RateLimitedPool.__init__(self, rate, per)

########################################

from requests import Request, Response, Session

def cb(res):
    print(res.text)

def worker(session, req):
    cb(session.send(req.prepare()))

def main():
    #pool = RateLimitedProcessPool(rate=10, per=1) # 10 requests per 1 second
    pool = RateLimitedThreadPool(10, rate=10, per=1) # 10 requests per 1 second
    start = time.time()
    session = Session()
    for _ in range(100):
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(session, Request(method='GET', url='https://httpbin.org/get'),))
    # Wait for all tasks to complete
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('Total elapsed time:', time.time() - start)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```